# Bitcoin c-lightning node on Synology cannot connect to bitcoind

Tags: core-lightning

I'm trying to setup a bitcoin lightning node on my NAS (Synology), following this tutorial: https://bitcoindev.network/running-a-lightning-node-on-synology-nas/

Unfortunately I get the following error (log):

```
lightningd: WARNING: default network changing in 2020: please set network=testnet in config!
bcli: 
Could not connect to bitcoind using bitcoin-cli. Is bitcoind running?
    
Make sure you have bitcoind running and that bitcoin-cli is able to connect to bitcoind.

You can verify that your Bitcoin Core installation is ready for use by running:
    
        $ bitcoin-cli -testnet echo 'hello world'   

2020-06-30T19:45:20.256Z INFO plugin-bcli: Killing plugin: Plugin exited before completing handshake.
The Bitcoin backend died.
lightningd: WARNING: default network changing in 2020: please set network=testnet in config!
```

My lightning.conf contains the following:

```
alias=myalias
network=bitcoin
bitcoin-rpcuser=myusername
bitcoin-rpcpassword=mypassword
bitcoin-rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
bitcoin-rpcport=18332
log-level=io
```

I've tried several parameters for bitcoin-rpcconnect (internal ip, external ip of my bitcoin node including the right ports).

Since my bitcoin node is running on mainnet I try to setup the lightning node for mainnet as well.

So does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that `lightningd` isn't using the mainnet (notice the `-testnet` in the `bitcoin-cli` line), are you sure the config is in the correct place? Notice that you call the file `lightning.conf` but it should really just be `config` in the correct directory.

Comment: I tried to name the file just ```config``` but unfortunately it gives the same error. So any ideas what else it might be?

Comment: You can always pass any options you have specified in the config on the command line, `alias=myalias` just becomes `--alias=myalias` and so forth. That eliminates at least the config filename source for issues.